# Using different scales for secondary axis for ggplot function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, iris-dataset, biplot

I am trying to create a biplot from iris data set using ggplot2 package. I have used below code to generate the biplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)


# Load iris dataset
data(iris)


# Run PCA and extract scores and loadings
iris_pca <- prcomp(iris[-5], scale. = TRUE)

scores <- as.data.frame(iris_pca$x) 
scores$Species <- iris$Species

loadings <- iris_pca$rotation

# Create biplot
biplot <- ggplot(data = scores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
          # Scores on primary scales
          geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
          # Loadings on secondary scales
          geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = loadings[1,1], yend = loadings[1,2]), 
                       arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", angle = 25)) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = loadings[2,1], yend = loadings[2,2]), 
                       arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", angle = 25)) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = loadings[3,1], yend = loadings[3,2]), 
                       arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", angle = 25)) +
          geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = loadings[4,1], yend = loadings[4,2]), 
                       arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", angle = 25)) +
          # Primary scales
          scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-3, 3), name = "PC1") +
          scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 3), name = "PC2") +
          # Secondary scales
          scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 1.2, name = "Loadings on PC1")) +
          scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 1.2, name = "Loadings on PC2")) +
          # Theme
          theme_bw()

biplot
```

The above code results in a biplot as shown below:

[image: Boiplot]

How can I use a different secondary axis scale (`limits = c(-0.8, 0.8)`) which only affects zooming in the arrows and does not affect the primary scale (also not the scores or points)? Is there any possible way to achieve this? I would be thankful for your cooperation.

Regards,
Farhan

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51844068/2530121) is probably the easiest to understand.

Comment: The link provided by @LeroyTyrone does not address my specific requirement. Most of the solutions mentioned in the answers demonstrate the use of different secondary y-axis with the same primary x-axis. Although I also checked the link of the answer accepted by the original poster, the provided codes didn't work for me. In my case, I want to plot arrows with a different secondary x and y-axis, which is different from the primary x-axis. Essentially, I want to plot the arrows as a second plot, with a completely transparent background, overlaid on the first point chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A secondary scale can't be specified independent from the primary scale, i.e. the secondary scale always derives from the primary according to transformation specified via `sec_axis()`. This said, both the primary and the secondary scale have to be specified via one `scale_xxx_continuous` command. Moreover, the transformation specified via `sec_axis()` will only affect the breaks, the limits and the labels of the axis. It will not touch the data. Instead *you*  have to take care of that by appropriately transforming the data using the inverse transformation applied on the scale. Finally, I simplified your code a bit by using just one `geom_segment` to add the arrows.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3

loadings <- as.data.frame(iris_pca$rotation)
loadings$Species <- rownames(loadings)

scale <- 2
# Create biplot
ggplot(data = scores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_segment(
    data = loadings, aes(
      x = 0, y = 0,
      xend = PC1 * scale, yend = PC2 * scale
    ),
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), type = "closed", angle = 25)
  ) +
  # Primary scales
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(-3, 3), name = "PC1",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / scale, name = "Loadings on PC1")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(-3, 3), name = "PC2",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / scale, name = "Loadings on PC2")
  ) +
  # Theme
  theme_bw()
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

[image]

Comment: The answer by @stefan is really what I wanted to achieve. Thank you so much.